# Changing Wallet Password

Tags: cleos, wallet

How would a user go about changing the password on their EOS wallet?  When I create a new wallet using `cleos`, I'm given back a randomly(?) generated password that is extremely long an unmemorable.  `cleos` does not provide any mechanism that I can find for changing this password.

Is there a built in mechanism in the `wallet_plugin` for changing the password of a wallet?

Comment: Investigating the source for the Wallet Plugin, I found a set_password method.  This method is only ever called on wallet creation with a random password.  It seems like it would be straightforward to extend the Wallet Plugin and the Wallet API Plugin to expose the ability to change a wallet's password.  Anyone know why EOS hasn't chosen to expose this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

**As far as I know, it is not.** But your question is reasonable. The wallet has only a master key, so you should be able to enter the master key first and enter a new one.

This key is not used for signing transactions, but for opening wallets only.

Even if it is not now, it seems to be a possible function in the future. It would be nice to have eos github as an issue so that it can be reflected.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can change wallet password for a given keypair.